# Angular returns $$state object - Angular and Kinvey

Tags: javascript, angularjs, kinvey

I have the following function:

```
 $scope.save = function() {       
    var promise = Kinvey.DataStore.get('books','5631713ddc168ca90f0202b6');
    console.log(promise);
```

Here's the console.log:

```
d {$$state: Object}
$$state: Object
pending: undefined
processScheduled: false
status: 1
value: Object
_acl: Object
_id: "5631713ddc168ca90f0202b6"
_kmd: Object
password: "teste"
teste: "teste"
username: "testeasdf"
__proto__: Object
```

How can I get the "password", "teste" and "username" value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
Kinvey.DataStore.get('books', '5631713ddc168ca90f0202b6', function (response) {
    console.log(response.password)
});
```

Or:

```
var promise = Kinvey.DataStore.get('books','5631713ddc168ca90f0202b6');
promise.then(function(response) {
    console.log(response.password)
});
```

Comment: Tku so much Michelem, the second one works like a charm.